# Count number of point for a librato metric

Tags: metrics, librato

I'm trying to build a composite metric to know how many point are sent on a period for a specific metric.
The closer stackoverflow response to this is about counting the number of source, and I failed to change it to do what I want ([How can i count the total number of sources my metric has with Librato?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38627895/how-can-i-count-the-total-number-of-sources-my-metric-has-with-librato))

The metric in question is a timing on a function execution, that receive around 20k values on peak hour
At first, I sum-ed the series with a count aggregation, and the pattern I had then was close to what I expected, but regarding our logs, it always differ

The composite I made was like that

```
sum(s("timing", "%", {function:"count"}))
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the librato support told me the composite do what I want

The differences with the logs were due to errors during metrics sending